# Redo not working correctly for (readline) `vi` command-line editing

Tags: bash, shell, readline

I'm using `vi` command-line editing:

```
shopt -o -s vi
```

My problem is that while undo (`u`) works as expected, that is not true redo (`.`).

In particular, if I've the following command-line `AA BB CC`, then positioning the cursor on the first `B` and executing the commands `dw` (delete word),`u` (undo),  and `.` (redo), yield the result `AA BB`, while I would expect `AA CC`.

Any ideas?

Source: https://catonmat.net/ftp/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet.txt

Comment: `.` is repeat, not redo. Fire up vim and run `:h .` if you can.

Comment: Ohh, but the cheatsheet says "redo". Anyways, do you know how to redo in vi mode (readline)?

Comment: In vim it’s Ctrl-R but that starts incremental search in readline-vi

Comment: Classical vi didn't have redo. vim added it as ^R, and nvi added it a different way (by changing the meaning of the `.` operator after `u`). The question is: which one is readline trying to emulate?

Comment: @Wumpus, I guess readline-vi maps C+r to redo, but bash intercepts it and starts incremental search, correct? Who/what is "nvi"? Can you show how to remap `.` to redo in readline-vi?

Comment: You probably mean that you expect `AA CC`, not `AA BB CC` at the end (that's what a real vi is doing, and what the standard requires). Please clarify.

Comment: @mosvy - sorry, yes of course, you're right. What can I do to properly redo, like I normally do with `^Y` in none readline-vi?